# Partition into sets of positive outer measure

Tags: set-theory, real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu^{\star}$ denote Lebesgue outer measure. Suppose $X \subseteq [0, 1]$ and $\mu^{\star}(X) > 0$. Can we divide $X$ into uncountably many sets $\{X_i : i \in I\}$ such that for every $i \in I$, $\mu^{\star}(X_i) > 0$?

Comment: For $X = [0,1]$ it seems that this was proved by Sierpinski and Lusin in 1917, but I can't get hold of the paper.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8085/set-of-finite-measure-uncountable-disjoint-subsets-of-non-zero-measure#comment17345_8087

Comment: Are people downvoting / voting to close because they think this is trivial? It doesn't seem so to me, though it may well be known.

Comment: Note this is equivalent to asking if $X$ may be partitioned into uncountably many non-measurable sets.  I guess the result for $X = [0,1]$ implies the same if $X$ has positive inner measure.  So we're left with the case that $X$ has zero inner measure.

Comment: If the additivity and the cofinality characteristics of the measure-zero ideal are equal, then there's an easy affirmative answer.  But the equality of those two characteristics is quite a strong hypothesis, since they are at the bottom and top (respectively) of Cichon's diagram.

Comment: @NateEldredge, here is a copy of the corresponding CR volume: http://archive.org/details/ComptesRendusAcademieDesSciences0165

Comment: @AndreasBlass, I guess this article of Shelah shows that you do need some hypothesis: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9705213v2.pdf

Comment: @RamirodelaVega Thanks for the Shelah reference. You should probably post it as an answer, so that the question doesn't languish in unanswered limbo.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I just did. I think one can get away with a milder hypothesis since the uniformity number might be larger than the additivity of the null ideal.

Answer (score 8):

Suppose that the cofinality and the uniformity number of the null ideal are equal to $\kappa$. Fix a cofinal family of null sets $\{N_\alpha: \alpha \in \kappa \}$ and a bijection $\varphi=\langle \varphi_1,\varphi_2 \rangle$ from $\kappa$ onto $\kappa \times \kappa$. We define inductively a sequence $\langle x_\alpha : \alpha \in \kappa \rangle$ of distinct elements of $X$ by choosing $x_\alpha$ from the set $X \setminus \left(N_{\varphi_2}(\alpha) \cup \{x_\beta : \beta \in \alpha\} \right)$, which is non-empty since we are taking away from $X$ a null set. Now just let $X_i=\{x_\alpha : \varphi_1(\alpha)=i\}$ for $i \in \kappa$. The $X_i$ are clearly disjoint and since $x_\alpha \in X_i \setminus N_j$ whenever $\varphi(\alpha)=\langle i,j \rangle$, they are non-null sets.

On the other hand, Shelah proved in [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9705213v2.pdf) that if it is consistent that there is a measurable cardinal then it is also consistent that there is a non-null set $X$ which cannot be partitioned into uncountably many non-null sets.